# show git modifications on the command prompt within windows git-bash

Tags: git, bash, mingw

I would like to display file changes (add, modify, delete) on the git bash command prompt similar to using (a) posh-git with powershell and (b) vcprompt on cygwin.  Problem with (a) is that powershell aliases clash with my bash ones I'd like to use.  Problem with (b) is that I don't want to install both cygwin and mingw - ideally just stick with mingw if possible.

Anyone have this working?

Comment: This is the time to suggest a move to using `zsh`. Git/SVN prompts are a breeze with `vcs-info`.

Comment: is it possible to run zsh on mingw?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I have no experience with mingw. I guess it might be possible, but you'll have to try it out.

Answer (score 0):

Take a peek at git prompt:

http://volnitsky.com/project/git-prompt/

It's open source so you can plunge right down into the bash code.

Comment: is there any way to get this working with mingw?  the script seems to fall over at the first hurdle (missing tput).